# How to set default configuration in R version 3.1.1 to output Rplots.ps instead of Rplots.pdf

Tags: r, pdf

I have a file name, **test.R** and the content is :

```
yvalues = runif(50)

plot(yvalues)
```

I had written the batch mode command :
**R --no-environ --no-save < "test.R" > "out.txt" 2>&1**

On executing the above command in windows 7 with R version 3.1.1 and R version 2.0.1 respectively, I observed two cases

**Case 1.** with R version 3.1.1 it produces two output files, i.e out.txt and **Rplots.pdf** in the working directory

**Case 2.** with R version 2.0.1 it produces out.txt and **Rplots.ps** in the working directory

**Note : Rplots.pdf is output by default in version 3.1.1 while Rplots.ps is output by default in version 2.0.1**

**I want to output by default Rplots.ps in R version 3.1.1. Is there any settings/configurations without writing additional code. How to do this in R version 3.1.1?**

Comment: You could just explicitly do a `postscript(file="Rplots.ps")` before the `plot` command and a `dev.off()` after it.

Comment: Thankyou so much David for your kind response. Is there any other way round or any other settings, rather than adding these extra code postscript(file="Rplots.ps") and dev.off(). For example in R version 2.0.1 you don't need to add these extra code, by default Rplots.ps is generated automatically. So here also I want Rplots.ps to generate automatically in R 3.1.1, so that I don't have to add these extra code, while writing any new R script.

Comment: You can put that code in a separate file, and run both files, 
e.g., with `cat 1.R 2.R | R --no-save`.
You could also add a hook (with `setHook`) to `before.plot.new`, in your `.RProfile`,
to open a new device.
(But is is cleaner to explicitly open the file for your plots. And `Rscript` usually gives a more readable output.)

Comment: Thankyou Vincent for you nice suggestion.But I am still curious and wondering why by defaults R.3.1.1 generate Rplots.pdf; while R.2.0.1 generate Rplots.ps.Is it because the developers did it purposely?. I still prefer the default way of generating Rplots.ps in R.2.0.1